# Expo-Auth session is not working properly

Tags: react-native, expo, google-signin

While implementing google login using the `expo-auth-session` package , I am getting some error that i don't have any idea about, It has been more than one day since i am stuck in this problem i cannot find a reliable source to use for implementing google login in my expo application. Is there any other way i can implement it in the react native expo application.

The error i am getting are :

```
 WARN  Linking requires a build-time setting `scheme` in the project's Expo config (app.config.js or app.json) for production apps, if it's left blank, your app may crash. The scheme does not apply to development in the Expo client but you should add it as soon as you start working with Linking to avoid creating a broken build. [Learn more][1]: 
 WARN  EventEmitter.removeListener('url', ...): Method has been deprecated. Please instead use `remove()` on the subscription returned by `EventEmitter.addListener`.
 WARN  Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 2):
 Error: Exception in HostFunction: Malformed calls from JS: field sizes are different.
```

What should i do ??
The [link](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/authentication/#google) to the documentation that i followed is :-

And this is what i used from the documentation.

```
import * as Google from "expo-auth-session/providers/google";

import * as WebBrowser from "expo-web-browser";  
WebBrowser.maybeCompleteAuthSession();


  const [request, response, promptAsync] = Google.useAuthRequest({
    expoClientId: expoClientId,
  });


const login = ()=>{
useEffect(() => {
    if (response?.type === "success") {
      const { authentication } = response;
      console.log(authentication);
    }
  }, [response]);

return (

 <Pressable style={styles.btn} onPress={promptAsync}>
              <Image
                source={require("../../../assets/g1.png")}
                style={styles.img}
              />
              <Text style={styles.text}>Sign in with Google</Text>
  </Pressable>

)
}
```

thank you any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 1):

In your app.json add following

```
"scheme":"com.yourpackage.yourapp"
```

this value must be same as your android.package and ios.bundleIdentifier